# Show/Hide div in home page by controlling from checkbox at admin page in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a control for allowing user to show/hide a div box at home page from admin site using ASP.NET MVC4. For example, if the user select to disable div box from admin site, the div box will be disappear when he go back to home page and same thing for showing div box as well.

I had been searching the whole day for the correct answer but still didn't find out the best answer yet. And I really have no idea how to link between admin site and home page.

The following is my admin page:

```
<div class="section-header">
    <div class="title">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Administration/Content/images/ico-configuration.png")" alt="" />
        @T("Manage LoginBox")
    </div>
    <div class="options">
         <input type="submit" name="save" class="t-button" value="@T("Admin.Common.Save")" />
    </div>
</div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        @*$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.EnableLoginBoxAtHomePage)").click(toggleLoginBoxEnabled);

            toggleLoginBoxEnabled();
        });*@

        function toggleLoginBoxEnabled() {
            if ($('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.EnableLoginBoxAtHomePage)').is(':checked')) {
                Response.Write("Surprise");
                $('#pnlShowLoginBoxAtHomePage').show();

            }
            else {
                $('#pnlShowLoginBoxAtHomePage').hide();
            }
        }
        function toggleLoginBoxDisabled() {
            if ($('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.DisableLoginBoxAtHomePage)').is(':checked')) {
                $('#pnlHideLoginBoxAtHomePage').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#pnlHideLoginBoxAtHomePage').show();
            }
        }
    </script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
<table class="adminContent">
        <tr id="pnlShowLoginBoxAtHomePage" onclick="toggleLoginBoxEnabled">

            <td class="adminTitle">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnableLoginBoxAtHomePage)
            </td>
            <td class="adminData">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnableLoginBoxAtHomePage)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnableLoginBoxAtHomePage)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="pnlHideLoginBoxAtHomePage" onclick="toggleLoginBoxDisabled">
            <td class="adminTitle">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisableLoginBoxAtHomePage)
            </td>
            <td class="adminData">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisableLoginBoxAtHomePage)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisableLoginBoxAtHomePage)
            </td>
        </tr>


</table>


}
```

And this is the div box that I want to show/hide at home page:

```
<div class="block block-loginbox" >
    <div class="title">
        <strong>@T("Login")</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
<div class="listbox" @*id="myloginbox"*@>
    <fieldset class="form-fields returning-wrapper">
            <legend>@T("Account.Login.ReturningCustomer")</legend>
            <dl>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Customer"))
                {
                    <dd class="message-error">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, T("Account.Login.Unsuccessful").Text)
                    </dd>


                    <dt>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email): </dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "email", autofocus = "autofocus" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                    </dd>

                    <dt>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password): </dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "password" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </dd>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </dd>
                    <dd class="forgot-password">
                        @Html.RouteLink(T("Account.Login.ForgotPassword").Text, "PasswordRecovery")
                    </dd>

                    <dd class="buttons">
                        <input class="button-1 login-button" type="submit" onclick="location.href='@registerUrl'" value="@T("Account.Login.LoginButton")" />
                    </dd>

                }
            </dl>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>

     </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you somewhat misunderstood the concept of web sites. Your pages shouldn't (and definitely CAN'T) communicate together. Every time you ask for a page, you get a new instance, unless it's specified as static and ... no no no, let's leave it at that - you can't.

The common solution to your "problem" is to implement some kind of `Settings` file/database table/whatever, that will store your settings when you save the page in your admin section. Then, when the user requests your home page, your code looks at these settings and determines what to do.

Update:

This is not asp.net specific, it's how all the websites work. HTTP is stateless, you need to persist the data somehow.

The basic idea looks like this:

`admin page -> load settings -> modify -> save settings`
`other page -> load settings -> if some setting applies, do something`

Your pages should communicate with the storage mechanism, not with each other, because as I've already said, that's impossible unless you violate pretty much every principle.

It doesn't matter that much `how` you store your settings, it can be a simple file containing pairs of keys and values. Or maybe a xml file, or a database... You get the idea. As long as it is available to the pages you need and doesn't violate security of your website, it's fine. It all depends on your needs!

Hope I don't have to show how to connect to the database and retrieve values...

Comment: I'm very new to this asp.net mvc4 and i don't really get it what you had explained.. mind showing me some examples to be more clearer?

Comment: @user2247985, or maybe try to explain which part of this flow you don't understand, I can't explain EVERYTHING to you. If you use Google, I bet you can find examples of individual steps everywhere, you just need to glue them together to fit your situation.

Comment: thanks a lot for the your updates and suggestions..i'll learn the basics again.. i'm trying to add settings and controllers for admin page now. thanks again.